# Mongodb as windows service

Tags: mongodb, windows

I am using mongo db with replica sets. I am starting the mongodb using command prompt.

Python Script:

```
os.system('start mongod --configsvr --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb1 --replSet conf --port 27019')
os.system('start mongod --configsvr --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb2 --replSet conf --port 27020')
os.system('start mongod --configsvr --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb3 --replSet conf --port 27021')

os.system('start mongos --configdb "conf/localhost:27019,localhost:27020,localhost:27021" --logpath E:\mongoSLogs\mongoLog.log  --port 26060')

os.system('start mongod --replSet conf --shardsvr   --dbpath E:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7 --port 27010 ')

os.system('start mongod --replSet conf --shardsvr  --dbpath F:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7 --port 27011 ')

os.system('start mongod --replSet conf --shardsvr  --dbpath G:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7 --port 27012 ')
```

I want to start the mongodb as a windows service.
Let me know how to convert the above in to windows service

Answer (score 0):

I would  recommend a [Configuration File](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html) instead a bunch of command line options.

There have a closer look at [Windows Service Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#windows-service-options)

Once you created the configuration file you can install the service like this:

```
mongod.exe --config c:\MongoDB\config\mongo.cfg --install
```

Note, the default service name is `MongoDB`. Unless you specify `processManagement.windowsService.serviceName` you have to use `os.system('net start MongoDB')` in order to start the service.

However, if you like to run more than one MongoDB service, the service names have to be distinct.

Running `start mongod ...` starts the service in foreground and the terminal remains open.